# Changing background colour of Readonly datagrid row

Tags: c#, wpf, telerik

I am using Telerik Datagrid view control in which few of my rows are readonly (so as per the visual style of readonly, background colour of row is gray).

Now when I change the Background colour to any other colour, readonly rows does not get affected. Their background remains gray only.

Following code I tried;

```
public void SetRowBackColor(string color, params int rowIndices)
{
    var brush = (SolidColorBrush)new BrushConverter().ConvertFromString(color);
    var s = new Style();
    s.Setters.Add(new Setter(BackgroundProperty, brush));

    var row = (GridViewRow)RadGridView.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(item);
    if (row == null)
    {
        RadGridView.UpdateLayout();
        RadGridView.ScrollIntoView(RadGridView.Items[item]);
        row = (GridViewRow)RadGridView.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(item);
    }
    row.Style = s;
}
```

Comment: Can you add what have you tried?

Comment: you can handle this in xaml only with a style ? does it has to be this way ?

Answer (score 0):

You can set this in XAML only, instead of setting color to row create a property for color and set that, now when row goes disabled, it should take your color.

```
<telerik:RadGridView.RowStyle>
    <Style TargetType="telerik:GridViewRow">
        <Style.Triggers>
             <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="True">
                <Trigger.Setters>
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding COLOR_Property}"/>
                </Trigger.Setters>              
             </Trigger>                         
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</telerik:RadGridView.RowStyle>
```

if your color doesn't change on runtime it would make sense to just add color name instead of COLOR_Property like -

```
<Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
```

Comment: For Telerik control, readonly cell's background doesn't change.